# Using broadcast receiver android to close app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Hi am trying to use broadcast receiver to trigger some action

1. Activity A will broadcast action "ACTION_EXIT" and come to Main Activity.
2. Whenever Main Activity receive the broadcast "ACTION_EXIT" it will close the app.

My code on Activity A (to send broadcast)

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Beacon_MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
broadcastIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
broadcastIntent.setAction("com.package.ACTION_EXIT");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
finish();
```

Code on Main Activity to receive the broadcast and trigger ACTION_EXIT

```
private void registerReceiver(){
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.package.ACTION_EXIT");
        registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver();
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
}

BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("onReceive", "Logout in progress");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "what the ****", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } 
        };
```

Don't know why it's not working, anyone can help should be much appreciate

> (app should be close when Main_Activity receive the broadcast on
>   resume)

Comment: If Activity A is on-screen, MainActivity is paused. Look at its `onPause()` method. The Receiver is unregistered there.

Comment: after send the broadcast, finish() method will close activity A and launch Main_activity. This is my intention

Comment: If you're starting Activity A from MainActivity, then use `startActivityForResult()` instead, and pass an exit value back to MainActivity in the result. No need for Receivers.

Comment: Activity A is start from Login_Activity. My flow is Main_Activity -->Login Activity---> Activity A. and the the requirement is to exit the app from Activity A

Comment: Assuming you're finishing LoginActivity after starting Activity A, then start Activity A with an Intent with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` added. The result from Activity A will then be delivered back to MainActivity.

Comment: So Activity A will start Main_Activity with the startActivityforResult(). How the Main_Activity check the rersult and close the app?

Comment: No, just `finish()` Activity A after setting the result. Gimme a minute, and I'll post a simple example.

Comment: thanks i am finding a way to exit the app from the Activity but still messing with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` is paused while `ActivityA` is running, during which time your Receiver is unregistered, and therefore not getting the broadcast. You can accomplish what you want with result forwarding instead.

In `MainActivity`, start `LoginActivity` with the `startActivityForResult()` method, and override the `onActivityResult()` method to handle the result.

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public static final String EXTRA_EXIT = "exit";
...

Intent actLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(actLogin, REQUEST_CODE);
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if(data == null) {
                return;
            }

            boolean shouldExit = data.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_EXIT, false);

            if(shouldExit) {
                finish();
            }
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in `LoginActivity`, add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to the Intent used to start `ActivityA`.

```
Intent actA = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
actA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
startActivity(actA);
finish();
```

In `ActivityA`, set a `boolean` value to indicate whether to exit, add it to a result `Intent`, set that as the result, and finish the Activity.

```
boolean shouldExit = ...            

Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_EXIT, shouldExit);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

The result will then be delivered back to `MainActivity`. This can also be done with only result codes, but I prefer using Intent extras.

Comment: i get these error https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oops, yeah, I accidentally deleted the null check when I edited my code. Hang on.

Comment: thanks a lot I tried again but actA only come to Main Activity (not exit the app). When i manually put shouldexit=true on Main Activity app can exit from Act A. May be the function boolean shouldExit = data.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_EXIT, false); is notworking

Comment: I'd have to see your code to tell you what's wrong. If you want to put it on Docs again, I'll take a look.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit?usp=sharing. this is my code. may be have the prob with the intent can not get the data back to Main Activity

Comment: That all looks correct. Could you please post the whole Beacon_Mainactivity class?

Comment: I have paste the code same link above. a bit long but i haved high light the part managing the exit () function

Comment: I found out that I have another intent to point to Beacon_Main_Activity that should add flag also. I modified and can now exit app from Beacon_Main. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Excellent!  I was trying to figure out what it could be, 'cause your code was working fine for me. Nice catch! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks alot. 1 last question is we to need to add flag for every activity? For example i ll add 1 more activity call checkActivity between login and beacon_main then need to add flag for intent to move from checkActivity to Beacon_main?

Comment: Many thanks for yrs help. I learnt much with the intent. Can i add your facebook or whatapp...? Mine is Lê Khánh Vinh. +6591204187. Im from singapore