# Navigating from Activity A->B->C - How to pass data from C to A in onBackPressed()?

Tags: android, android-activity

1. From `Activity A` call `Activity B`
2. from B to C and while calling `Activity C`
3. I call finish for `Activity B`, (to clear from stack history `Activity B`)
4. and in `Activity B` `onBackPressed()`, I pass data via `setResult()` from `Activity B` to `Activity A`, but in `Activity A` the data is `null` and `resultCode 0`.

How to get data from `Activity B` in `Activity A`?

Comment: Well, I can't find a decent duplicate question, atm, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33911485) demonstrates how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `finish()` from B when opening C. Instead, call C with `startActivityforResult()` and then pass the data back through B when `onActivityResult()` in B is triggered. Something like:

```
ActivityB {
    onCreate(Bundle) {
        startActivityForResult(ActivityC, 0);
    }

    onActivityResult(int, int, Intent){
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Edit:

Apparently adding the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` when calling B should actually achieve your desired result as well.

Learn somethin' new every day...

Comment: You can also send more than a flag with getIntent().putExtra(identifier, dataAsString).  Which you can then access in the onActivityResult with intent.getExtras().getString(identifier)

Comment: The flags should be applied via Intent.setFlags(int), putExtra() just added data to the Bundle passed with the Intent, so you would need to use a combination of both of those to achieve the desired effect

Comment: @Guardanis
Thanks , I have tried calling from A-> startActivityForResult(B) ,from B to C with startActivity() with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT and in C Activity in onBackPressed() I call finish and setResult() but in Activity A I receive null data

Comment: B has to call C with startActivityForResult as well, or else it will never return to B. Only A should have Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT

Comment: @Guardanis I'm pretty sure you don't need to start `Activity` C with `startActivityForResult()`. I believe the problem might be that the OP is calling `finish()` and/or the `super` method in `onBackPressed()` before `setResult()`.

Comment: @Mike If he was using B's onActivityResult() to transfer the data back to A, then wouldn't B have to start C with startActivityForResult() in order for B's onActivityResult() to ever be called? And is that the same case for Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT if B is going to finish() in between A and C?

Answer (score 0):

Where're multiple ways of doing this:

- Store the data from `Activity C` to [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)'s object and just read it in `Activity A`:

  ```
     ((MySuperApplication) getApplication()).setMyData(..);
  ```
- Pass it as Activity Result
- Store data to `SharedPreference` in `Activity C` and read it in `Activity A`. If it's a complex data structure - I'd suggest to use `gson`to serialize object and store it as a `string` and then deserialize it in `Activity A`

Choose the one you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

use shared preference

**C ACTIVITY**

`SharedPreferences sf = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sf.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();`

**A ACTIVITY**

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
mOutputView.setText(savedPref);`