# SharedPreferences doesn't work between activites

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a brain freeze as that obvious feature doesn't see to work for me and any help would be appreciated. Here is what I do:

1. Open activity A
2. Read SharedPreferences for that activity
3. Open activity B
4. Delete one of the two items in SharedPreferences object
5. Save preferences
6. Go back to activity B re-read the SharedPreferences I still see two items

Both activities seem to have their own personal instance of SharedPreferences.  Is there a better solution to sharing variables across activites, what am I doing here wrong?

Thank you

```
    //
// Activity A
//
SharedPreferences prefToDos = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref_ToDos", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorToDos = prefToDos.edit();

// Works OK I get 2 items for that activity
JSONArray jArrToDos = new JSONArray(prefToDos.getString("todos",null));


//
// Activity B
//
SharedPreferences prefToDos = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref_ToDos", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorToDos = prefToDos.edit();

// Works OK I get 2 items for that activity
JSONArray jArrToDos = new JSONArray(prefToDos.getString("todos",null));

//Yes button clicked
jArrToDos.remove(todoIndex);

editorToDos.putString("todos",jArrToDos.toString());
editorToDos.commit();
finish();

//
// Back to Activity A to onResume()
//
SharedPreferences prefToDos = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref_ToDos", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorToDos = prefToDos.edit();

// DOESN'T WORK I still get 2 items for that activity
JSONArray jArrToDos = new JSONArray(prefToDos.getString("todos",null));
```

Comment: jArrToDos.remove(todoIndex);

editorToDos.putString("todos",jArrToDos.toString()); what u get in jArrToDos here after removing?

Comment: @Radek first check whether your sharedpreference is update or not then check your onResume method is working fine in ActivityA. Try debugging this or printing log.

Comment: see this [click me for sharedpreference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42268095/7399521) i hope this will help you

Comment: is your both activity run on the same process this is generally when your activity have the different process

Comment: Don't get it all looks right but the deletion not propagating to another activity as if I was working with two different instances, different process as mentioned but not sure how to debug that, thank you for the ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. Try to print what you are getting after performing `jArrToDos.remove(todoIndex);` and check if the item is getting removed from the array.

To pass data from one activity to other you can use Intents, which is more preferable for local temporary sharing.

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KeyForTheValueToPass, ValueToPass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Radek need to come back on Activity A and then using his sharedpreference values. So how he pass intent onBackPress?

Comment: @ZakiPathan He can override onBackPressed() in Activity B.

Answer (score 2):

First try to use [apply()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) instead of [commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()).
Other things from your code seem to be correct.

Alternative to `SharedPreferences`,  You can

1. Start the Activity B using [`startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))
2. And pass the string through intent by  [`setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html?#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent))
3. Retrieve the string from intent in Activity A using [`onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

Answer (score 0):

i have another solution rather then delete  sharepreference store  "" (blank)which field you want to delete blank . when you come back next activity   you will not get value or you will get "" just put one if else in your code and validate .its working for me.